# Что такое русский дух? И чем Русь пахнет?

Tags: фольклор, литература

В пушкинском прологе к поэме "Руслан и Людмила" и во многих сказках устами бабы Яги говорится о русском духе. Так чем же Русь и русский дух пахнет?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Здесь "пахнет"не в значении "издавать запах", а в значении "что чувствуется, ощущается, ожидается"(по Ожегову)Ср. A царь, что день, грознее да грознее;
Чем это пахнет? плахой, либо ссылкой
И вечною опалой.
Островский. Дмитрий Самозванец.

Русью пахнет (и вообще "чем пахнет") - это иносказание — какие веяния, течения? -русские(какой дух? - русский)
[чем пахнет | academic.ru](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/michelson_new/11766/%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC)

Русский дух
(Народн.) То, что составляет русский народный характер, духовную суть русской нации. БМС 1998, 174..Ср. Волшебный град! там люди в деле тихи,.Но говорят, волнуются за двух.
Там от Кремля, с Арбата до Плющихи -
Отвсюду веет чистый русский дух.
Некрасов. Дружеская переписка. Петербургское послание.

Для Бабы Яги русский дух - предчувствие появления русского героя как силы добра, а для Пушкина поэма - предчувствие встречи с героями русских народных сказок, богатырей, защищающих Русь и идеи добра

Comment: >Для Бабы Яги русский дух - предчувствие появления русского героя как силы добра, а для Пушкина поэма - предчувствие встречи с героями русских народных сказок, богатырей, защищающих Русь и идеи добра

Почему-то **русский дух** обычно не нравится всякой **нечисти** в сказках (бабе Яге, змею). Обычно фраза начинается так: "**Фу-фу**, русским духом пахнет".

Comment: "Русью пахнет" - Странно, а я бы даже не думал, что трактовка "Русью пахнет" может вызвать какие-то затруднения или нуждается в комментариях. Значение-то вполне употребительно.
Вот "русский дух" - это понятно, точнее - непонятно современному человеку.

>Для Бабы Яги русский дух  
  
А разве там по тексту русский дух как-то связан напрямую с Ягой? Не сказал бы...  
Кстати, а кто она вообще такая, это Яга? Никто вопросом не задавался? И почему уменьшительное - Бабка-Ёжка?

Comment: >Почему-то русский дух обычно не нравится всякой нечисти в сказках (бабе Яге, змею).  
  
Не знаю, как там насчет змея, а Яга в первичном своём варианте была слепа (о чем есть упоминание даже в Вики). По запаху она различала гостей. Так что тут "русский дух" - вполне себе запах. Ни о каком "русском характере" или "духовной сути" тут и речи быть не может. Натерпелась старушка крепко от русских "добрых" молодцев, дураков-иванов и прочих любителей покуролесить в чужих избушках, вот и остерегалась.

Comment: ...и во многих сказках устами бабы Яги - так сказано в вопросе, потому и  ответ связан с её образом.
      Так чем же Русь пахнет - в вопросе указание именно на 1 значение глагола пахнет.

Comment: А о Яге вот здесь достаточно хорошо:http://allforchildren.ru/why/where18.php

Comment: >А о Яге вот здесь достаточно хорошо  
  
Спасибо, Людмила, но я-то с вопросом знаком. Думал, может кому ещё интересно. 
Что действительно не понятно - так это образование "Бабка-Ёжка". 

>..и во многих сказках устами бабы Яги... 

Не понял, к чему и кому это. Если мне, то я не возражаю. Я насчет того что а) у Пушкина они не связаны б) фраза "ффу, русский дух" имеет (или может иметь) вполне конкретное для БЯ наполнение. Я вообще склонен считать, что все эти ура-патриотические наполнения и прочая заумь в трактовке русских сказок - наносное, позднейшего периода.

Comment: Про "Русью пахнет". Я особо не задумывалась над этим вопросом,  он не казался мне сложным.  Ученики, когда читали пролог, спрашивали больше о персонажах.   
 "Чем Русь пахнет?" - спросила дочка в 4 года (тоже из пролога). Чем поставила нас в затруднительное  положение. Мы восприняли вопрос буквально. Ничего путного в голову не приходило, кроме запаха хлеба, сена, злаков (наверно, сказалось советское прошлое). Ответ, удовлетворивший ребенка, дала умница- племянница (5 класс). Она сказала, что Русь пахнет грибочками, ягодками и полевыми цветами.

Comment: Про Ягу хорошая статья. Мы недавно еще выясняли, почему у избушки курьи ножки. Тоже интересно :)

Comment: Об этимологии Яги есть в Вики http://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Баба-Яга#section_2

Comment: >Об этимологии Яги   
  
Я видел. Не самая, кстати, убедительный источник. 
Думал, может, кто не знает. 
А вот про Бабу-Ёжку нигде нет, увы.

>"Чем Русь пахнет?" - спросила дочка в 4 года  
  
А кстати... Я, читая эти строки в этом возрасте (ну или годом-двумя позже) воспринимал хвойный лес с совершенно особым, "грибным" запахом...  Он был мне хорошо знаком с самого раннего детства. Вряд ли у малышей какие-то могут быть какие-то принципиально другие ассоциации... А что могут сказать современные городские дети?

>Ответ, удовлетворивший ребенка, дала умница- племянница.
Поддерживаю. Умница.

Answer (score 4):

Пропп, "Исторические корни волшебной сказки", классический научный труд. Вкратце: русский дух - запах живого человека в царстве мертвых, границу которого, как правило, охраняет Баба Яга - сама полутруп (костяная нога и др. атрибуты). Много интересного, кроме того.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я читала отрывки, до полного текста не добралась. А надо бы!

Comment: Вообще-то в отношении "полутрупа" могут быть разнве мнения. Да и охрана границы - только одна из версий роли Б-Я в славянском пантеоне духов, божеств и кумиров...

Answer (score 3):

Ой, только в другом месте помянул...
Если очень кратко, то тут обыгрывается два значения слова "дух": душа и запах. 
В первом случае "русский дух" - это душа, а заодно с ней - ещё и культура, традиции, антураж...  Сейчас бы сказали "менталитет". 
Подробнее сейчас не могу, но уверен, что еще будут ответы.

Answer (score 3):

Я, конечно, согласен с сопоставлениями `дух=душа`, но все же считаю, что есть и прямая аллюзия к *издавать запах*.

У каждого народа действительно есть свой запах, который является функцией образа жизни, привычек, еды и проч. проч.

Каждый из нас это замечал на собственном опыте бывая в других странах. Конечно, чем более схож образ жизни народа, тем более и схожи запахи и наоборот. В странах ЮВА или Африки, любой согласится, что аборигены пахнут совсем "перпендикулярно". В Европе это менее заметно ну и т.д.

Спросите у любого инородца живущего на окраине России пахнут ли русские по другому? Вам ответят утвердительно!

Так что Пушкин глубоко прав, когда пишет про "Русский Дух" он прав и в прямом и переносном смысле - ну гений, что с него взять!

Answer (score 0):

Да, господа хорошие... Люди-то нынче растут русскоязычные, да не русские по Духу. Ни родители,  ни школа, похоже, своей роли воспитания не исполнили. Самые начитанные могут сослаться на Проппа и "аса" Пушкина. Русские сказки и сказы никто не знает. Вот  и вопросы странные и ответы престранные... Итак: 1. Русский Дух встречается во всех сказках, где герой встречается с врагами всего рода людского, с нечистью и с Врагами Руси-Матушки. Он спускается в нижние миры и там - тоже самое. Вывод: не привязывайте ответ к Пушкину и Бабе-Яге. 2. Отчасти правы те, кто пишет про "обычный" запах.  Но - только отчасти: и нелюдь и "подземные" жители воняют не по-людски. А русские, с утра мывшиеся и парившиеся не реже раза в неделю, для степняка, которому просто негде мыться по-нормальному, тоже пахнут по-особому. 3. Для тех,  кто уловил запах чисто вымытого русского тела на своей территории,  это был сигнал, что пришло время отчитываться за свои мерзкие дела. Ибо Русский Дух не терпит Зла (насилия)  и Лжи. Вот и били богатыри врагов человечества и врагов Руси. Учуял Русский Дух - кирдык тебе. Кассым баш, как говорится.